# What is the best JOIN for this? (Many to Many) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

For these tables here (circled)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDx8X.jpg

What would the best join be to use for them , I tried using OUTER join but it would not return any rows even if there was matching data.

Thanks

QUERY

```
select *

from 

hr

OUTER JOIN

hr

ON

hr.procedure_id = procedure.procedure_id

OUTER JOIN

staff

ON

staff.staff_id = hr.staff_id

Where hr.procedure_id = procedure.procedure_id
```

Comment: Please post the query that you have tried.

Comment: It depends on what you want to return in your query! What do you want?

Comment: I want any row that of staff that matches the staff id in "hr" table and any row in "hr" table with its foreign key matching procedure table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
select p.*, hr.*, s.*
from procedure p
left outer join hr on p.procedure_id = hr.procedure_id
left outer join staff s on hr.staff_id = s.staff_id
```

That will give you results unless there are no rows in procedure.

There are different ways that you could put these together, though, depending on what exactly you want. I don't know what "hr" stands for here, so I can't use common sense to figure that out.

Comment: hr = human resources - it is for linking all staff personal that were involved in one procedure row

Comment: What are 'quantity' and 'quantity_sterilized'? Those don't seem like they belong in a table about people attending a procedure.

Comment: Quantity is the total people in the operating theatre , the quantity sterilized are the ones who have been scrubbed for medical operation and are actually involved and not observing the operation

Comment: e.g. there are 4 doctors in the operating room , 2 are sterilized therefore we can assume the other two are just observing the operation

Comment: Aren't those really properties of the procedure itself? The way you have it put together, that information is being listed separately for each person who is involved in the procedure. If the hr table will include both those who are sterilized and those who are not, then you might want to consider putting a field like 'sterlized_yn' in the hr table; then, you can use a query to get the quantity of people in the operation, and another query to get the number sterilized.

Comment: That's the more "correct" way to represent that information in a relational database model. You could also put those counts in the procedure table; it's sort of a hack, but it might be more efficient and simpler to report on. (Which you prefer may depend largely on whether your database is intended more for reporting or for collecting the data as it's produced.) But putting them in hr just seems wrong.

Comment: Yes but there could be so many different staff types in the operating room e.g. doctor, nurse, radiologist, physiologist, trainee doctor, anaethestist, xray technician. My client wants to know how many were involved and how many were observing - the assumption is that any sterilized staff are involved and any non sterilized are not involved . Thanks

Comment: @sqlmole let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2059/discussion-between-nate-c-k-and-sqlmole)

Answer (score 1):

I would [suggest reading up on JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). It is hard to know what you are looking for. We won't make that decision for you.

Comment: I want any "staff" rows that are linked with "procedure" table through "hr" table. The joins don't tell you how to do a many to many relationship

Comment: look at the examples. just combine the logic.

Comment: It is much easier to get a human to help than WIKIPEDIA! There is too much crap to read through in it and it is not clear. I am dyslexic too :(

Comment: @sqlmole - theres a ton of other resources too. your domain is not going to be totally clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with JOIN at all, and let the query optimizer handle it for you.

```
select * from hr, procedure, staff
where hr.procedure_id = procedure.procedure_id and staff.staff_id = hr.staff_id
```

Comment: Thanks but if I am wanting to retrieve all of my other tables e.g. patient , procedure_name, department, dosage, procedure_events, resources and med_items how will that tie in?

Thanks - i really like your code it seems simple , going to test it

Comment: This still does joins, it just doesn't use the explicit "JOIN" syntax.